# HTML5 Audio play two sounds at once on one link

Tags: html, audio, html5-audio

I need two sounds to trigger and thus play simultaneously when hovering over one single link.

```
<audio id="sound1" src="sounds/sound1.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="sound2" src="sounds/sound2.mp3"></audio>

<a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('sound1').play();>Play</a>
```

Looking for a simple way to do this. I've looked at other questions like this but the answers were crazily complicated.

Comment: You can do one thing.. Play first audio on hover and play 2nd on completion of first..  audio.addEventListener('ended', PlayNext);

Comment: You gave me an idea how to solve it. Have it play the second sound onmouseout...! Thanks for your help.